# SignalR - replacing the default implementations for IGroupManager and IHubConnectionContext

Tags: asp.net, signalr, .net-4.8

We have a single-tenant .net 4.8 SignalR app which we should rewrite to be multitenant. The app has a hundreds of hubs. In order to make it multitenant, we have to change all the group names that we are currently using.

For example,
**hub.Groups.Add("adminGroup")** should become **hub.Groups.Add(*tenantName* + "adminGroup")**;

and
**hub.Clients.Group("adminGroup")** should become **hub.Clients.Group(*tenantName* + "adminGroup")**

The approach to append ***tenantName*** to all the strings in thousands of places is quite error-prone. That's why we want to apply a more generic solution to this problem. Is there an easier way to override the default behaviour of ***hub.Groups.Add*** and ***hub.Clients.Group***? We want to make a change to only one place in code, so we are sure that every time we call a Group, it's the group for the specific tenant.

I imagine that there is a way to inherit the default implementations of IGroupManager and IHubConnectionContext, then apply the logic for the tenants there and finally simply inject our custom implementations.